# CCNA: OSPF adjency over Framerelay

Tags: networking

I set up framerelay and I can successfully ping from R1 to R2. The problem I'm having is that there aren't OSPF advertisements. I explicitly stated broadcast when mapping the IP's. Here are my configs:

R1:

```
interface Serial0/0
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.252
 encapsulation frame-relay
 ip ospf network broadcast
 ip ospf priority 0
 no keepalive
 serial restart-delay 0
 clock rate 64000
 frame-relay map ip 10.10.10.2 201 broadcast

router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
```

R2:

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.12.0.1 255.255.255.0

interface Serial0/0
 ip address 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.252
 encapsulation frame-relay
 ip ospf network broadcast
 ip ospf priority 0
 no keepalive
 serial restart-delay 0
 frame-relay map ip 10.10.10.1 201 broadcast

router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 10.12.0.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
```

When I ask for routing info:

```
R1#sh ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     10.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       10.10.10.0 is directly connected, Serial0/0
```

I do not understand why it doesn't work. I'm using GNS3.

Comment: Can you capture traffic to make sure OSPF's neighbor advertisements are making it across the link, and check the output of `show ip ospf interface Serial0/0`?  Might be able to get it going like this, but it looks like Cisco's [recommended config over a frame relay](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_configuration_example09186a0080094054.shtml) is to use subinterfaces.

Comment: aah nice, add it to an answer and I shall reward you a V

Comment: Indeed you need to use subinterfaces to be able to send broadcasts and to avoid routing loops at the same time